# Radius of convergence of $z^{2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

find the radius  of  convergence  of the  power series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2n}   $  ?

I got $\infty$ because $R= \lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{z^2}$

Is it true ?

Comment: no, that power series doesn't converge when $|z|>1$

Comment: All coefficients are $0$ or $1$, unlike you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substitution, it is a geometric series in $z^2$ As the geometric series has a radius of convergence equal to $1$, it means that the radius of convergence of the given  series is $\sqrt{1}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is sufficient to show that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\mid a_{n+2}z^{n+2}\mid}{\mid a_{n}z^{n}\mid}<1$$
which is equivalent to $\mid z\mid^2<1$.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sum sequence is not Cauchy for $|z| \geq 1$.

For $|z| \leq 1$, note that the series would converge for z real and positive (geometric series) and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.